# ListView para ArrayList

Tags: android, listview

Tenho um `Listview`, um `EditText` e um `Buttom`. Quando eu clicar no botão eu quero que ele jogue o que tem no `ListView` em um `ArrayList`, para que eu possa inserir o que foi escrito no `EditText` no `ArrayList` e depois usa-lo para carregar o `ListView`.

Em resumo seria isso:

```
ArrayList = ListView;
ArrayList.add(valor);
ListView.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter(this, ..., ArrayList));
```

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" >

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/imgBtIncluirPessoaTarefa"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/edtPessoaEditarTarefa"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_input_add" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/edtPessoaEditarTarefa"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/imgBtIncluirPessoaTarefa"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="Pessoa"
        android:inputType="textPersonName" >

        <requestFocus />
    </EditText>
</RelativeLayout>

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listaPessoasEditar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="130sp" >
    </ListView>
</RelativeLayout>

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" >

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/imgBtIncluirTarefa"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/edtTarefaEditarTarefa"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_input_add" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/edtTarefaEditarTarefa"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/imgBtIncluirTarefa"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="Tarefa"
        android:inputType="textPersonName" >
    </EditText>
</RelativeLayout>

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listaTarefasEditar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="130sp" >
    </ListView>
</RelativeLayout>

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Onde esse `Button` está? Quer pegar a lista inteira ou apenas uma linha? Se for uma linha, como você sabe a linha?

Comment: quero pegar todas as linhas!

Comment: Poderia incluir seu layout?

Comment: parece que ele retorna um Adapter, mas da erro pra converter em arrayList

Comment: Você quer o valor que está no `Adapter` ou o valor atual dos itens da lista? É possível iterar sobre o `Adapter` e usar o `getItem`, já que infelizmente o `ArrayAdapter` não fornece acesso a lista diretamente. Mas ao acessar o `getItem`, você está acessando os valores que usou para popular os elementos e não o atual.

Comment: quero pegar o que tem no ListView!

Comment: Entendi @CésarAlves, vou tentar preparar uma resposta assim que eu tiver menos enrolado, ainda hoje.

Comment: Consegui fazer aqui mano! Muito Obrigado! @Wakim

Comment: se puder, coloque o código que resolveu como pergunta e aceite-a, pode ajudar outras pessoas que venham a ter esse problema.

Comment: @CésarAlves Considere postar a solução deste problema e com isso ajudar outras pessoas.

Comment: Eu só dei um getAdapter() e inseri a String no adapter retornado.
Depois dei um notifyChange...().
Sucesso!

Vlw a todos!